# How to provide an end date when an account is reentered for a mistake made sometime earlier?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have accounts with a start date and end date as null, with a mistake on customerId.

say it looks like this

```
Account: 1234 Startdate: 7/1/2019 enddate:null customerId: 01546
Account: 1234 Startdate: 7/2/2019 enddate:null CustomerId: 1546
```

The zero was never supposed to be in the first customerId, so by going back and fixing the mistake the person has created both of these. I want to be able to give that first one with the customerId: 01546 an end date of the start date of where the person went in and made the correction. I would greatly appreciate your help on how to do this. Thank you

Comment: How many of such pairs do you have? Does your table have a unique key?

Comment: maybe something like this `Enddate = CASE WHEN LEFT(customerId,1) = '0' THEN  MIN(Startdate)OVER(PARTITION BY Account) ELSE Enddate END`

Comment: @PM77-1 this table has 4 primary keys two referring to the start date, and of course the account number should be unique which is why when someone makes a change to an accountnumber it adds the duplicate and I want to make sure the first one created has an ending date to show that there are no duplicates if that makes sense

Comment: You can't have 4 Primary Keys on a table - do you mean a Primary Key that covers 4 columns?  Even then, how does the same column appear more than once?

Can you include your table schema in the question - including the Key definitions

Comment: first you should figure out what your primary key is, then you can update this row's `enddate` using the primary key

Comment: does this means that both customers `01546` and `1546` exist ? If not then your database design is wrong and you should focus on fixing it